# Material Resistance - Temperature increase in two merged bars

Tags: material-science

**Context:**

Material Resistance, Temperature increases and affects axial forces

[image: Fig. 1]

The structure consists of an aluminum bar (AB) size L, which is surrounded by a copper wrap (CD), merged to the aluminum. Both materials temperature is incremented equally. If the thermal expansion coefficient of aluminum is more than the copper one, which one of the following statements would apply?

A) AXIAL force for ALUMINUM is COMPRESSION and AXIAL force for COPPER is EXPANSION
B) AXIAL force for ALUMINUM is EXPANSION and AXIAL force for COPPER is COMPRESSION
C) AXIAL force in ALUMINUM bar ends (AC and DB) is EXPANSION
D) AXIAL force in ALUMINUM bar ends (AC and DB) is COMPRESSION

I would like if somebody can correct my thoughts, so that I really learn the WHY of the solution.

**My thoughts:**

If temperature increases equally for both bars, and Aluminum thermic expansion coefficient is bigger than Copper's one, for the purpose of this situation, this is the same as stating that Aluminum bar volume will try to increase a bit and copper bar will stay static.
If Aluminum bar tends to gets bigger (volume increment), it will have free space in the ends, to expand (hence AC and DB has axial force COMPRESSION, since it resists to expansion) and CD stays force-less because it cannot grow, because CD is copper bar and it stays apparently fixed, static.
So only **D** is right.
I really appreciate your comments and time. Thanks.

Note: Even if this seems a homework question, it is not, I seek to understand how things work, so that I can solve this problem on my own.

Comment: For compression or tension (the 'expansion' is a really bad bad name), there must be a force applied. What force is applied, and where is it applied?

Comment: @JonCuster There is no direct force applied. Only an increase of temperature that makes both materials expand. They expand in axial direction too, so, [my supposition] there should be compression reaction in them. Is that right? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Consider just the aluminum bar without the copper wrap. With increasing temperature what force is applies?